# can'' find the sys modul

Tags: python, sys

I want to start learing creating menu's, so, this is a script i found for testing.
There are no faults in it, but he doesn't show a window with the menu's.
I have looked for the reason and the problem is that he can't find the sys.

First the code I use:

```
import sys
```

```
print(sys.path)
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages')
from qtpy.QtCore import Qt
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
```

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def _init_(self, parent=None):
        
        super()._init_(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Probeersel")
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.centralWidget = QLabel("Hello")
        self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlingVCenter)
       self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
```

```
if __name__ == "_main_":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have allready uninstall anaconda and reinstall it. But, the same thing, not working.
I have put my save in the anaconda folder, but still not working.

I have looked all ready her to find a solution, but no, still not working :(

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "can't find the sys"?

Comment: It's very unlikely that out of all modules, `sys` would be missing. And there are problems, at least in the text posted here: `'C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages'` should be `'C:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages'`, note the duplicated ```\``` characters. `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)` misses a space in front of it, it should start at the same column as the other lines before it.

Comment: This is the outcome of the print(sys.path):

Comment: ['C:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\x07naconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3', '',

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Maabr\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Comment: That's all the output.

Comment: As Anaconda is mentioned, and the code is split into many blocks: if you're trying this in a browser, so inside a Jupyter notebook, I'm not sure if Qt can run there. Never tried it myself, so it might run, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Yes, the ```C:\x07naconda3``` comes because of the single ```\```, make them double.

Comment: When i run it, the first thing appearing is this: debugfile('C:/Users/Maabr/anaconda3/Test/menu.py', wdir='C:/Users/Maabr/anaconda3/Test')
> c:\users\maabr\anaconda3\test\menu.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 import sys
      2 
      3 print(sys.path)
      4 sys.path.insert(0,'C:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages')
      5 from qtpy.QtCore import Qt

Comment: If `print(sys.path)` works at all, you clearly _did_ find the sys module, because you're using it.

Comment: It would be better to show your actual error, and let us interpret it, than to describe it based on something you found on the Internet that may or may not be trustworthy or accurate.